# Convergence of the series $\sum \frac{(n)^{1/2}}{(n+1)^3 \log(n)}$ using which test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum \frac{(n)^{1/2}}{(n+1)^3 * \log(n)}$

I was hoping someone could tell me if this series converges and how to show that it does. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I apologize, the title is misleading. I just need to know if the series converges and using which methods. I edited the title

Answer (score 1):

Simple comparison:

$$\frac{n^{1/2}}{(n+1)^3\ln(n)}<\frac{n^{1/2}}{n^3}=\frac1{n^{2.5}}$$

And this clearly converges by the Cauchy condensation test, integral test, or p-series.